# Dynamically changing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to change the javascript of a page inside iframe. (I don't have cross domain issues)

Say I have two html files:

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function change() {
 var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
 
 var html = $("#iframe_id").contents().find("html").html();
 html = html.replace(/---someText---/mg, text);

 $("#iframe_id").contents().find("html").html(html);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Dynamic Alert Text: <input type="text" id="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Change Iframe" onclick="change()" />
<br><br>
<iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframe_id" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and iframe.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test() {
 alert("---someText---");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Text is: ---someText---</div>
<input type="button" value="Test Me!" onclick="test();" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace alert message of the iframe.html with the text I get from index.html
Just replacing it doesn't work.
Is there a work around.

Comment: Instead of having the iframe preexisting, generate the iframe with your data in it using your javascript instead of editing it and then place it into the DOM

Comment: I still need to change it, when user changes input and hits "Change" button again.

Comment: Then on change button again destroy the iframe in the DOM and recreate. You cannot edit anything inside the iframe that will create huge issues in security. The answer below uses a good workaround though. It's the same as storing the information on a server and having the iframe pull that except on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session, cookies or window object or localStorage to get and set values, I think this is the easiest way to solve your issue

in index.html set a localStorage or window.sessionStorage variable to hold  your text:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
          localStorage.setItem("myItem",text)
```

in iframe.html get that variable's value

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("myItem"));
```

or

```
alert(window.sessionStorage.getItem("myItem"));
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is (at least for my own case), I actually don't know what is inside iframe.html. I only search for special tokens (---someText---), create a form in index.html for user to change. They can be html, css or js. A js function may be as simple as alert, or very complex.

Comment: Then if you don't have control of the data in the iframe html then what you want can't be done.

Comment: So, you may try this , var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
 var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframe_id");
        var iFrameHtml = iFrame.contentDocument ||iFrame.contentWindow.document;   // now you have control over Iframe global document object, and set or get a value on that like 
 with   iFrameHtml object,    after that point you can set and get anything in your iframe

Comment: yes, I areadt can get and set html, my problem is when I set it with the new html with different js, it still alert's the old one.